# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've spent the last 2 hours researching this question because it seems to be asked often but haven't found anything close to  my issue. I am using Chrome & I previously was having issues where my styling disappears from the page but stopping my server and restarting it somehow fixed the issue and it worked fine for days now my styling is disappearing again and the console is giving me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`  for the last several lines in my html file, for which the code is

```html
<head>
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2/dist/email.min.js"
  ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
  <link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    sizes="72x72"
    href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png"
  />
  <link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    sizes="114x114"
    href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png"
  />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="css/nivo-lightbox/nivo-lightbox.css"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nivo-lightbox/default.css" />
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,600,700,800,900"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nivo-lightbox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact_me.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

The last 7 `script` tags is where the console is saying I have an unexpected `<` . I am also getting an error on 5 .css files `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/css/filename.css".`

I also figured I'd share what my network tab is also showing. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is, the styling was working perfectly fine yesterday, all day and today just stopped. I cleared my cache and also tried shutting down and restarting my server to no avail. I also double checked that the src files have no typos and are pointing to the correct path. Sorry for the long post, I appreciate any help ! Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Look at the data coming back from those URLs. See what it actually contains. If all the JS files have extra `<` in them then something is broken and there's no way to tell what from the HTML with the URLs in it.

Comment: `js/jquery.1.11.1.js` — that version of jQuery has [known security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-6538/product_id-11031/version_id-286364/year-2019/Jquery-Jquery-1.11.1.html). Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: I would try removing all 7 of those scripts, and then add them back one at a time, save, reload the page, until the error re-appears. That may expose the culprit file.

Comment: Maybe throw your page into [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/)...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Like the previous comments, I have a feeling there's an issue with those files not existing on the server, and so they're returning some sort of HTML as a default value since it can't find them on the server. If you look at the contents of those files either in Chrome web inspector or visiting the URL directly, they are all likely returning HTML, but the browser is expecting JavaScript.

Comment: @PaulT. — The OP said the error occurred for each of them: They are _all_ the culprit URL.

Comment: @Siguza — The only HTML error here is the missing `<title>` and that couldn't cause this problem.

Comment: @Quentin thank you, I'm looking at those files and I'm not even sure what I should be looking for. I've never touched any of them & everything was working fine yesterday.

Comment: Don't look at the files. Look at the resources returned by the URLs.

Comment: Just throwing this out there: something that's tripped me up in the past, is moving JavaScript from my HTML, out into files, but keeping the <script> tags

Comment: @Quentin, I'm sorry but how do I look at that?

Comment: Click on it in the bottom of your screenshots. Or type it in to the address bar of the browser.

Comment: @Quentin oh okay...I did do that actually and it just brings me back to the page

Comment: And *that* is why you get the error. The URL isn't pointing to what you think it is. Now debug your web server to find out why.